# Установка  модулей  других  разработчиков

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться детально, как именно установить модули других разработчиков.

Comment: @yarik, Поясните вопрос. Вы хотите через утилиту, к примеру, `easy_install` устанавливать или собирать из исходников? А также, какие модули, на С++ и тд, или только на Python?

Answer (score 1):

```
если устранавливаете какие-то пакеты из архивов то вам просто необходимо установить утилиту easy install документация к ней есть..
если посредством инсталл пакетов - то там обычно просто надо указать путь до папки питона
а если одиночный файл: то скопировать его в папку python/Lib/ или любую папку которая есть в sys.path
```

вот и все чудеса

Answer (score 1):

Установить распакованный пакет:

```
python setup.py install
```

Установить пакет из индекса питон-пакетов (http://pypi.python.org/pypi) по имени:

```
pip install django
```

или

```
easy_install django
```

Установить пакет из репозитария, например git:

pip install -e git+http://github.com/zakhar/sorl-thumbnail.git#egg=sorl-thumbnail